# Update Input field value with value from a range slider using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to modify a how-to example which I got from W3Schools

The example is a range slider which display the value of the slider inside a `<span>`
tag

What I would like to do is display the value inside an input field

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
```

Source: [W3Schools range slider example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_rangeslider_round)

I would like to display the value inside an input field instead of the `<span>`
tag so I have tried to modify the example:

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <input type="number" id="demo" name="fname" value="">

</div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo").value = slider.value;
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
```

but this doesn't work as it only display the initial value and does not update if I move the slider knob

Comment: Don't get the `value` immediately. Use `output.value = this.value;` in the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the element's reference in the output var & instead of innerHTML you could just use the value attribute.

Here's the updated code for your reference:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.value = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.value = this.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <input type="number" id="demo" name="fname" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

setting an onchange function on the range `onchange="myfunction()"`so this function will be called every time you change the slider.

inside the function setting `demo.value` to `slider.value`

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");


function myfunction() {
  demo.value = slider.value
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange" onchange="myfunction()">
  <input type="number" id="demo" name="fname" value="">

</div>
```

Comment: Why did you decide to inline the JS?

Comment: why not? he is a beginner so its easier to understand. he can always learn about `event listeners` when he gets a little grasp on `JS`

Comment: The OP is already using a listener in the JS code - `oninput` - so it's clear they understand them.

Comment: ok you are great. Congratulations